# how to make pop up alert when receive new data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 php page that have different function. the first page is use to upload some data to mysql. and the second page is use to show the data from mysql. my problem is how to make pop up notification on second page when receive new data from mysql? this is my source code.
sorry for my english. thanks.

-> upload.php

```
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) { 
enter $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'tryjade' );

if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error ); }

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES ('{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])}')";
$insert = $mysqli->query($sql);


if ( $insert ) {
echo "Success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_id}";
} else {
die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}"); }

$mysqli->close();
}
```

->index.php

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$koneksi = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $koneksi ) {
die('connection failed: ' . mysql_error()); }
$sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM user';
mysql_select_db('tryjade');
$ambildata = mysql_query( $sql, $koneksi);

if(! $ambildata ) {
die('Gagal ambil data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ambildata, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "ID :{$row['id']}  <br> ".
     "NAME : {$row['name']} <br> ";
}
mysql_close($koneksi);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax function.In the upload page,you can also include the select query for getting the latest results from the table.print that data and show the result in the index page as ajax result.
For example:

```
index.php

$.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url: 'update.php',
       data : datas you need to send,
       success:function(msg)
       {
        $("id of the div to show the result).html(msg);
       }
});
```

update.php

```
    if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) { 
enter $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'tryjade' );

if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error ); }

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES ('{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])}')";
$insert = $mysqli->query($sql);


if ( $insert ) {
echo "Success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_id}";
```

//write the select query and echo the result either in the form of table
    } else {
    die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}"); }

```
$mysqli->close();
}
```

Comment: thx for your ansewer, but it still cant work:( i confused how to write $.ajax bcs i havent use this before @Techy

Answer (score 0):

You should use cookies for hold the last loaded data id of sql table then it match by max id again load and write alert code if cookies id is less to max id.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [session](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) as session allows you to store data between requests.

> session_start() and $_SESSION

upload.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) { 
      $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'tryjade' );

........

if ( $insert ) {
     echo "Success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_id}";
     $_SESSION['message'] = "Your Message";
} else {
```

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';

.........

echo $_SESSION['message'];

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ambildata, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   echo "ID :{$row['id']}  <br> ".
   "NAME : {$row['name']} <br> ";
```